# SignalR: GetHubContext does not call client methods, but referencing the hub directly does

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, signalr-hub

I had a troubling issue dealing with SignalR (v 2.4.1) hubs last week, and despite doing enough by the documents, I could not broadcast messages without hacking my way through it. For some extra context, this is a self hosted (Owin) hub attached to a windows service.

MSDN documents, and runtime errors (**Using a Hub instance not created by the HubPipeline is unsupported**), suggest that we are supposed to get the hub context by calling `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ThisTypeOfHub>()`, and at that point we can make calls to the client.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub)

When I originally set up calls to the clients, I was doing it this way:

```
public void OnDisplayMessage(string message)
{
  var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ThisTypeOfHub>();
  hub.Clients.All.BroadcastToClient(message);
}
```

The browsers that contained the method and had connected to signalR never got called, however. The clients could call server methods, and even the server methods would send out a callback which the clients responded to, but the hub context could never call out to the client methods when called from *outside* the hub. In the end, I directly brought back the hub reference in the IoC container, and called out to clients using that, as shown below.

```
public class LogicWithUI : Logic
{
  Hub hub;

  public LogicWithUI(IDependencyInjectionContainer container) 
  {
    this.hub = container.Resolve<ThisTypeOfHub>();  // ThisTypeOfHub inherits from Hub
  }

  public class OnDisplayMessage(string message)
  {
    try 
    {
      this.hub.Clients.All.DisplayMessage(string);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
       //do nothing, no webpage has connected yet
    }
  }
}
```

This way it is finally working fine (you can see the catch placed there for when an error occurs -- only when no webpages have connected to this yet), but it doesn't make sense.

1. What would cause the HubContext called from outside the hub to not actually broadcast the method?
2. Why would the unsupported error get thrown *only when no clients are connected*?
3. Are there any obvious mistakes I'm overlooking here?

The primary goal here is to have a functioning product, but I also want to do it the right/documented way. It's a little confusing when that way isn't working.

I also understand I might have left out some important details regarding the SignalR configuration, I can answer any follow up questions, but wanted to start with the basic explanation.

Comment: Please make sure that your code will compile at the second code block. If not it'll be harder for is to see the issue.

Comment: Sorry about that, thanks. I stripped down a few elements of the class to remove the clutter, and only halfway deleted some stuff.